# unable to retrieve the contents of files in the SPO document library

Tags: ios, swift, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/drive/items/root:/drivename/filename:/content

Requesting this URL with GET, we were able to retrieve the contents of the file. (Confirmed around ~October 2020)
The cause is unknown, as it could not be retrieved when run in Graph Explorer and no error code was returned.
Response "- 0 - 336ms"

I was executing the request in swift, but the code has not been changed since the process of acquiring the file contents was successful.

**Access Permissions**

[image: Access Permissions]

Comment: I was able to upload the file.
Is there a different URL to retrieve the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions required for retrieving the list of drive items , Please refer this document [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

To get the file and contents of the file , please follow this API's

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/items/root/children)

Or if you want to list the items in a sub-folder:

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/items/%7Bitem-id%7D/children)

Please refer this document [List Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)